# Regex required for checking Multiple fixed Strings values in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am looking for help for below scenario in big query in Regex

My input column can get anyone or more of the following delimited by a semicolon:

```
Anonymisation
Pseudonymisation
Hard Deletion
Enhanced Access Management
Cold Storage
Other
Managed through Risk Processes
Null
```

For this i have tried with below query:

```
SELECT INPUT_COL, case when REGEXP_CONTAINS (INPUT_COL,r'((\b(PSEUDONYMISATION|ANONYMISATION|ENHANCED ACCESS MANAGEMENT|HARD DELETION|COLD STORAGE|OTHER|MANAGED THROUGH RISK PROCESSES)\b)|(\b(PSEUDONYMISATION|ANONYMISATION|ENHANCED ACCESS MANAGEMENT|HARD DELETION|COLD STORAGE|OTHER|MANAGED THROUGH RISK PROCESSES)\b:?\b(PSEUDONYMISATION|ANONYMISATION|ENHANCED ACCESS MANAGEMENT|HARD DELETION|COLD STORAGE|OTHER|MANAGED THROUGH RISK PROCESSES)\b:?\b(PSEUDONYMISATION|ANONYMISATION|ENHANCED ACCESS MANAGEMENT|HARD DELETION|COLD STORAGE|OTHER|MANAGED THROUGH RISK PROCESSES)\b:?\b(PSEUDONYMISATION|ANONYMISATION|ENHANCED ACCESS MANAGEMENT|HARD DELETION|COLD STORAGE|OTHER|MANAGED THROUGH RISK PROCESSES)\b:?\b(PSEUDONYMISATION|ANONYMISATION|ENHANCED ACCESS MANAGEMENT|HARD DELETION|COLD STORAGE|OTHER|MANAGED THROUGH RISK PROCESSES)\b:?\b(PSEUDONYMISATION|ANONYMISATION|ENHANCED ACCESS MANAGEMENT|HARD DELETION|COLD STORAGE|OTHER|MANAGED THROUGH RISK PROCESSES)\b:?\b(PSEUDONYMISATION|ANONYMISATION|ENHANCED ACCESS MANAGEMENT|HARD DELETION|COLD STORAGE|OTHER|MANAGED THROUGH RISK PROCESSES)\b:?\b(PSEUDONYMISATION|ANONYMISATION|ENHANCED ACCESS MANAGEMENT|HARD DELETION|COLD STORAGE|OTHER|MANAGED THROUGH RISK PROCESSES)\b))$')=True then '' else 'E' END as Error_Ind from( SELECT 'ANONYMISATION:ABCD' AS INPUT_COL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ANONYMISATION:ENHANCED ACCESS MANAGEMENT:HARD DELETION' AS INPUT_COL UNION ALL
SELECT 'OTER' AS INPUT_COL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCD:ENHANCED ACCESS MANAGEMENT' AS INPUT_COL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ANONYMISATION:PSEUDONYMISATION' AS INPUT_COL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ANONYMISATION:PSEUDONYMISATION:HARD DELETION:ENHANCED ACCESS MANAGEMENT:COLD STORAGE:OTHER:MANAGED THROUGH RISK PROCESSES' AS INPUT_COL)
```

and the result as below

[image]

In the picture highlighted in yellow is a wrong string as the first value ABCD is not defined in my list of values but in the result it is showing as Correct value.
At the same time if you see 5th record its giving me as error correctly

Can any one help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'ANONYMISATION:ABCD' AS INPUT_COL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ANONYMISATION:ENHANCED ACCESS MANAGEMENT:HARD DELETION' AS INPUT_COL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'OTER' AS INPUT_COL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABCD:ENHANCED ACCESS MANAGEMENT' AS INPUT_COL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ANONYMISATION:PSEUDONYMISATION' AS INPUT_COL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ANONYMISATION:PSEUDONYMISATION:HARD DELETION:ENHANCED ACCESS MANAGEMENT:COLD STORAGE:OTHER:MANAGED THROUGH RISK PROCESSES' AS INPUT_COL
)
SELECT INPUT_COL, 
  CASE TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(INPUT_COL, r'(?i)Anonymisation|Pseudonymisation|Hard Deletion|Enhanced Access Management|Cold Storage|Other|Managed through Risk Processes|Null', ''), ':')
    WHEN '' THEN '' 
    ELSE 'E' 
  END AS Error_Ind 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Another option would be

```
#standardSQL
SELECT  
  (
    SELECT IF(COUNT(1) = 0, '', 'E')
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(INPUT_COL, ':')) value
    WHERE NOT UPPER(value) IN UNNEST(SPLIT(UPPER('Anonymisation|Pseudonymisation|Hard Deletion|Enhanced Access Management|Cold Storage|Other|Managed through Risk Processes|Null'), '|'))
  ) AS Error_Ind,
  INPUT_COL
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with same result

```
Row Error_Ind   INPUT_COL    
1   E           ANONYMISATION:ABCD   
2               ANONYMISATION:ENHANCED ACCESS MANAGEMENT:HARD DELETION   
3   E           OTER     
4   E           ABCD:ENHANCED ACCESS MANAGEMENT  
5               ANONYMISATION:PSEUDONYMISATION   
6               ANONYMISATION:PSEUDONYMISATION:HARD DELETION:ENHANCED ACCESS MANAGEMENT:COLD STORAGE:OTHER:MANAGED THROUGH RISK PROCESSES
```

Comment: Hi Mikhail.. along with above combinations if there is space in between the two words like below..how to validate then  ANONYMISATION: ABCD